# Vue default Boolean type props behavior is not retained when declaring multiple types

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If you have a component `MyComponent` with a prop `myProp` declared as:

```
props: {
    myProp: Boolean
}
```

We can expect a default behavior from using `myProp` simply as `<MyComponent myProp/>` which gives `true`.

However, you cannot use that convenience anymore when you have multiple types for `myProp`.

E.g.

```
props: {
    myProp: [Object, String, Boolean]
}
```

How do you retain the default behavior for adding `myProp` attribute without explicit value?

Answer (score 0):

Fluked the solution:

```
props: {
    myProp: [Boolean, String, Object]
}
```

You just have to put `Boolean` as the first element in the array.